# How can I create pushable remote Mercurial repos that works over SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, git, repository, mercurial

I have been using git for a while and I use git and ssh. I have couple bare repos on my server which I use to pull and push on multiple computers. Now I want to try Mercurial for some of my projects (non coding projects). I have been looking around for how to do this but so far all have is murky bytes and bits.

How do I create a remote repo that works over SSH and easily pullable and pushable? I want this repo to accept the incoming pushes into master like the way git does. It is going to be my remote central repo , so I do not want to interact with it beside remote pulls and pushes.

It is easy with Git. I just create a bare repo and start pushing to it or pull from it. What is the proper wayu to do it with Hg on Linux? I have a running Ssh server, so this question only deals with the Hg side of things.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ever easier in Mercurial for single user (with shell-access to repo): just read [Shared SSH](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SharedSSH) wiki-page and [Creating Repositories Over SSH](http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2009-10-02-creating-repositories-over-ssh/) tip and have remote SSH-repository

Just one note: in Mercurial world `ssh://hostname/path/to/repo` and `ssh://hostname//path/to/repo` give you access to repositories in **very different locations**